# pdflatex and TexStudio includegraphic problem

Tags: graphics, pdftex, texstudio

I'm having (*no Boundingbox*) problem **even using pdflatex engine**. It's strange because it's working fine with MikTex but not Texstudio. Sadly I want to stick to TexStudio now. I've included the code bellow as well as the snapshot of my Texstudio configuration.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{test.pdf}
\end{document}

Cannot determine size of graphic in test.pdf (no BoundingBox). \includegraphics{test.pdf}
```

The snapshot of the configuration:
[image: builder information]

And the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=latex 2014.2.21)  5 MAR 2014 12:42
entering extended mode
**test.tex
(U:\Thesis\Report\test\test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex\latex\base\report.cls"
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@chapter=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 91.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex\latex\graphics\dvips.def"
File: dvips.def 1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
(U:\Thesis\Report\test\test.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.


! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in test.pdf (no BoundingBox).

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 \includegraphics{test.pdf}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

File: test.pdf Graphic file (type eps)
<test.pdf> [1

] (U:\Thesis\Report\test\test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 530 strings out of 493922
 6268 string characters out of 3148909
 53647 words of memory out of 3000000
 3891 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 25i,4n,19p,683b,142s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on test.dvi (1 page, 308 bytes).
```

Comment: what default option is being used. Perhaps the pdftex.def driver code was not picked up, the log file will show the files included

Comment: I've included the log file but I have no idea what's going on there. Please take a look and check it for me. Thanks

Comment: Try PDF-chain, and not DVI->PDF chain. That is what I have and it works.

Comment: Thanks this works. I believe I've tried PDF-chain before but it gave me various weird problems but now it works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your configuration is choosing dvi in the "build and view" option that you show so you are using latex/dvips/ps2pdf rather than pdflatex. You can not include pdf files using this route.
You need to either include EPS files, or switch your build to use pdflatex.

Comment: @JuriRobl yes just saw that at the end of the log, I'll rewrite this entry

Answer (score 0):

[image: Snapshot taken after correcting my settings]

I too faced the same problem, but after several trials, i corrected the error. finally the settings shown in the figure are working.